# Calling a virtual function from within an inherited function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I've tried to map it out in my head, but honestly I have no idea what's really going on here.
**What exactly is happening** when I add and remove the virtual keyword from the below example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A() { me = "From A"; }
    void caller() { func(); }
    virtual void func() { std::cout << me << std::endl; } // THIS LINE!
private:
    std::string me;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { me = "From B"; }
    void func() { std::cout << me << std::endl; }
private:
    std::string me;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.caller();
    B b;
    b.caller();
    return 0;
}
```

With the virtual keyword, it prints  "From A", then "From B".
Without the virtual keyword, it prints "From A", then "From A".
So far, this is the only time I've found a use for virtual functions without pointers being involved. I thought that if the virtual keyword was removed, the compiler would do the standard thing which is to overload the inherited function and end up printing "From A", and "From B" anyway.
I think this is deeper than just the VTable, and that it's more about the way it behaves in particular circumstances. Does B even have a VTable?

Comment: `caller` essentially calls `this->func`, where `this` is an `A*`. This invokes dynamic dispatch IFF `A::func` is virtual.

Comment: @dyp, that deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call

```
func()
```

is equivalent to

```
this->func()
```

so there *is* a pointer involved.

Still, there's no need to involve pointers to understand the behavior.

Even a direct call of e.g. `b.func()` has to work *as if* it's a virtual call, when `func` is virtual in the statically known type. The compiler can optimize it based on knowing the most derived type of `b`. But that's a different kind of consideration (optimizations can do just about anything).

Comment: For me, I did need pointers to understand the behaviour. Mostly because when using simpler examples that don't have pointers pointing to derived class objects etc, using the virtual keyword appears to make no difference. Even though you've informed me of the difference in how it's dealt with.

Comment: I presume this means that B, since it's inheriting A that uses a virtual, also has a VTable, just like A. And that when you call "caller()" from b, it doesn't use the VTable. However when "caller()" calls "func()", it then must use the VTable to resolve which "func()" to use. Am I right when I say that it figures out which VTable to use by going up through the call chain until it reaches b?

Comment: Vtables are an optimization not mandated by the C++ standard, but used by all C++ compilers. They make it unnecessary to walk up the inheritance chain. You're right that the call of `caller` is non-virtual, while the call of `func` is virtual. To avoid surprise when or if a base class member function is changed from virtual to non-virtual, you can use the keyword `override` for the override in a derived class. That only compiles if it's actually an override.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you won't see the difference:

- With the virtual function, the compiler will generate a call via the VTable and at runtime, each objects will call the right function for their real class.
- With the non virtual function, the compiler determines at compile time the right function to call, based on the objects defined class.

Now try the following, to see the virtual function in action:

```
A  *pa = &b;       // pointer to an A: valid as b is a B wich is also an A.  
pa -> caller();    // guess what will be called if virtual or not.
```

No need for pointer to experimenting with virtual functions.  You can observe the same effect with references as well:

```
A& ra = b;       // create a reference to an A, but could as well be a parameter passed by reference.
ra.caller();
```

Virtual functions are useful for polymorphism.  The idea is that you work with a general object of a class, but you don't know at compile time, if at runtime the object will really be of this class, or if it will not be a more specialiszed object (inheriting from the class).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP’s question.

Comment: I understand this. The confusing part was that the virtual function was already in action without it.

Comment: I answered only on the question in bolt.  I didn't answer on purpose on the VTable, because these are not defined in the normative part of the standard.  Vtables are only means compilers usually implement virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue of virtual dispatch, what may bring extra confusion, is that you have two `me`s, one declared in `A` and another declared in `B`. These are two distinct objects.

An object of type `B` has two data members of type `std::string`; one on its own, and one incorporated into the subobject of type `A`. The latter one, though, is not immediately available in the methods of type `B` because its name is eclipsed by the new `me` introduced in this class (though you may use a qualified name, `A::me` to refer to it).

Therefore, even though the bodies of `A::func` and `B::func` seem identical, the identifier `me` used in both of them refers to different members.

Comment: @dyp: no, it's `private`.

Comment: You make a good point. I'll edit the variable names later to prevent confusion amongst those that happen to stumble across this.

Comment: Ha, could still be confusing though. My comment stands!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, private or not private, in C++ (unlike, say, C#) name resolution comes *before* access check.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: it sounds like you're arguing against something. wtf is that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: it sounds like you're arguing against something. wtf is that. :-) Inaccessibility of a member is quite another question from its name not being found.